# Laravel Json response function

Tags: php, json, extjs

I am currently developing an application in Laravel (v4.2.11) which is using ExtJS (v4.2.1-gpl).

As part of my ExtJS application, I am developing a JSON response that is used by ExtJS. However, I want to do the following thing:

```
return Response::json(array(
  'menusystem' => array(
    'listeners' => array(
      'click' => function() {
        location.href = 'test'
      }
    )
  )
);
```

I do know this is not valid JSON. However, this is the way how the previous developer of the application did it that way. I'd like to know if this is possible within PHP, Laravel or JSON.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What did the previous developer do, actually? Also, PHP (language) != Laravel (php framework) != JSON (data format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$response = array(
  'menusystem' => array(
    'listeners' => array(
      'click' => "%%%function() {
        location.href = 'test'
      }%%%"
    )
  )
);

$response = json_encode($response);
$response = str_replace('"%%%', '', $response);
$response = str_replace('%%%"', '', $response);
return $response;
```

It's only general conception. You can detect function structure in special macro etc.